# Copying files slows down the system, making it unusable (KDE Neon)

Tags: kde, file-copy, ntfs-3g

I regularly update my system running [KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org/), but this time after the update something broke in the "file copy" process. The system slows down during copying to external hdd or pendrive so much so that the system becomes unusable, CPU usage runs too high. Initially after reading some online forums I thought it was some taskbar animation issue, but after I tried to copy big files using terminal and tty, the results are the same in both cases, so the problem is not with the animations. Any ideas on what's causing the issue?

My system specs:

- CPU: Intel i5-7200U
- RAM: 8GB
- HDD: 1TB

Comment: I can see you tagged `ntfs-3g`. Does this occur only when copping to an NTFS external drive?

Comment: What process(es) is/are at the process list in `top` when this happens?

Comment: https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=309 may also be a useful source of support, but this is a valid place to ask your question, too.  In your BIOS, is ACPI selected? Please advise.

Comment: The problem is for both ntfs and fat 32. It looks like a linux kernel update (version 5.3) i got due to system update has caused the problem. mount.ntfs which is on the top consume 60 to 70 % cpu followed file.so ~20% and kwin ~20% .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research I noticed the kernel was updated to 5.3 from 5.0, it was certainly due to system updates. After downgrading the kernel to 5.0 all things came back to normal. I dont know whats wrong with version 5.3, but it resulted in very high cpu usage specially mount.ntfs process which is around 60 to 70 percent. The whole kde desktop seems to freeze when coping of large files is going on. Even on fat 32 system the problem was there. I also tried the kernel 5.4, same issue was there.